# I want to create function that creates a new label tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter. Please read the above question and please help.

Comment: Welcome to [SO] we are here to help with code that dosent work as expected. If you are looking for a tutor or a tutorial you can find them in different platforms. [tkinter tutoraial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuoSKkSEhQg&list=PL6lxxT7IdTxGoHfouzEK-dFcwr_QClME_)

Comment: What is stopping you from doing what you want? Have you tried creating a function that creates new labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk

root = Tk()

def create_text_lable(display_text:str,x:int,y:int):
    text = Label(root, text=display_text)
    text.grid(row=y,column=x)

create_text_lable("Hello World!",0,0)
create_text_lable("Hello World!",1,1)
create_text_lable("Hello World!",2,2)

root.mainloop()
```